# MySQL Last Insert and multiple web servers

Tags: php, mysql

I am to the point now where I need to scale to multiple web servers plus a db server, instead of hosting mysql, and the site on the same box.

I use 'mysqli_insert_id' in php to return a key value for another following operation.  As I scale out and more users hit the site, is this still a reliable method for getting the last insert ID?  If for some reason, two requests hit almost simultaneously, is there any chance that using mysqli_insert_id could return the wrong insert ID since both inserts and select calls would happen seemingly instantly?

Comment: You're doing really well. Isn't it time to hire a professional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/getting-unique-id.html):

> For LAST_INSERT_ID(), the most recently generated ID is maintained in
>   the server on a per-connection basis. It is not changed by another
>   client. It is not even changed if you update another AUTO_INCREMENT
>   column with a nonmagic value (that is, a value that is not NULL and
>   not 0). Using LAST_INSERT_ID() and AUTO_INCREMENT columns
>   simultaneously from multiple clients is perfectly valid. Each client
>   will receive the last inserted ID for the last statement that client
>   executed.

So yes, `mysqli_insert_id` will remain a reliable method for getting the last insert ID.